# $L^p$ and $L^1$ norms

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

As $L^p$ norm of $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^{n}$ is defined as
$$
\|f(t)\|_p:=\left(\int_S\|f(t)\|^pdt\right)^{1/p}
$$
I have two questions:

> - What kind of norms for the function $f(t)$ in the above right hand side? Any norm on $\mathbb R^n$?
> - What's the defition of $\|f(t)\|_1$? Is $\int_S\|f(t)\|dt$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are integrating in the $L^p$ norm is not $||f(t)||^p$, but $|f(t)|^p$ ($||f(t)||_p$ is what you are defining). For $||f(t)||_1$, just substitute $p=1$.

Comment: "Yes" to both your questions.

Comment: @AlbertoDebernardi Since the function $f(t)$ is a vector-valued function, then what is the mean of $|f(t)|$?

Comment: @user143763 If you write $f(t)=(f_1(t),\ldots,f_n(t))\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $f_1,\ldots,f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, then $|f(t)|=\sqrt{f_1(t)^2+\ldots+f_n(t)^2}$. It can be done for any normed vector spaces, see the Bochner integral.

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks for your comments, and the reference does help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually the $L^p$-norm is in the context of complex-valued functions. Then the "norm inside the integral" is the absolute value of $f(t)$.

And you get $\left\| \, f\, \right\|_1$ by substituting $p \mapsto 1$: $$\left\| \, f\, \right\|_1 = \int_S \left| \, f(t) \right| \, \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my function $f(t)$ is a vector-valued function.

Comment: Where did you encounter this? Is there some reference one could check?